# Checking internet connection using broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I use a dongle for connecting to the internet while I am using my android app with the emulator and I use a Broadcast receiver for checking the connection. But it always give me the result

```
"NetworkInfo: type: MOBILE[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED reason: simLoad extra: internet, roaming: false, faliOver: false, isAvailable: true".
```

When the dongle is disconnected it gives the same result which is wrong.

Why is that so? Give me some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the emulator only the internet support from connect to your computer, can you try un-plugin your computer cable, check the result right or not.

suggestion test the network run in the real device.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but may be someone else use it: press F8 to enable/disable the emulator 3G network.